# server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Tags: 16.04, apt, ssl, tor

I am trying to follow steps described on [Tor Project Debian Repository](https://support.torproject.org/apt/) page to install latest LTS tor packages.

When I run the `apt update` command, I am getting following error

```
<omitted unrelated lines>
Err:10 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial Release
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
<omitted unrelated lines>
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

My Ubuntu version is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: This is normal, because you are trying to update a non-supported (End-Of-Life) version.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: I hope your server is offline; 16.04.4 means you've not been supplying upgrades & security fixes since before 2-Aug-2018 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/08/02/ubuntu-16-04-5-lts-released/) as that was when 16.04.5 ISO was released; however installed systems upgraded weeks before that date.  An updated system though reported itself as 16.04.7 when *standard* support ended (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-16-04-7-lts-released/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xenial packages are no longer available at that repository because Xenial is EOL. Please upgrade to a newer, supported version of Ubuntu (e.g., 18.04, 20.04, etc).

You can either install a supported version of Ubuntu from a new download or, if you're feeling adventurous, you can [follow the instructions in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/167115) to upgrade manually from the terminal.